# How lucene can be used to search words prefixed with adverbs/negations?

Tags: lucene

I am a newbie to Lucene. I wanted to know how can i use Lucene to search a word which may be prefixed with an adverb. The document contains only words and no adverbs prefixed to them.

**For example**: If term to be searched is 'very beautiful' and my document contains
only beautiful, then i want a Hit. The word can also be prefixed with
negations like 'not very beautiful' or my not have a prefix at all
like 'beautiful'. I just can't drop off the prefixes because I need to
keep a track of Negations which change flow of further processing.

I tried Fuzzy search but results are not that satisfactory. Is there any way to find accomplish this?
I could not find relevant answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this, I would Google on "part of speech tagging" and "natural language processing". Once you have tagged your parts of speech, you could then apply Lucene indexing.

One way to implement this would be to index the words with their tags, like:

```
n:he v:is a:a aj:big n:man
```

for

```
he is a big man
```

where `he` and `man` are nouns, `is` is a verb, `a` is an article, and `big` is an adjective.

Comment: Yes, this is what i have done. After tagging, i took the word with adverb attached to it and was searching for it using Lucene. My focus is basically on how can i search for such type of words (as mentioned in my post)?